# How to read influxdb backup data with Python (with pandas or other tool)

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a data backup folder produced from an influxdb with the [backup and restore](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/backup_and_restore/) utility. This produces a `.tar.gz` file as mentioned in the reference.

I wish to open and process these data with Python (maybe pandas library or another python tool).

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: What is the format of files inside the archive???

Comment: @Corralien it is a banch of other `.tar.gz` files and some metadata files regarding he database, and the actual data I assume are in binary form. So I think you need to know exactly how the `backup` and `restore` processes work in influx to manually replicate the behavior if that is what you are alluding to. I am more interesting to know if there is a tool already available to do this.